# How can I get home scree after particular time duration ios

Tags: ios, session, timestamp

I would like to implement the time out functionality like windows session expiration.
My case is If i didn't touch the screes in 30 minutes I need to redirect the Login screen, other wise normal will need to work.

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self  
           selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:)name:10 object:nil];
```

then implement the method,

```
 -(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification*)notif
 {
      NSLog(@"10 mints looping");

     //calling login screen.

 }
```

but if I'm working in the views also the time expires.How to avoid this.Please any one suggest me to achieve this.

Sorry for the poor english and text formation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

> Implement a subclass of UIApplication to monitor all the touches in 
>   application.

And implement the following code also in that class

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   if (event) {

       [super sendEvent:event];
       NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
       if ([allTouches count] > 0) {

           UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
           if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan){

               [self resetIdleTimer];
           }
       }
   }
}
```

More Details:

`- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

- **Parameters**

  > event: A UIEvent object encapsulating the information about an event, including the touches involved.
- **Discussion**

  > Subclasses may override this method to intercept
  >   incoming events. Any intercepted events should be dispatched by
  >   calling [super sendEvent:event] after examining the intercepted event.

`- (void)resetIdleTimer` is the method in which you can schedule your timer.

go on .. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping..May I know the [super sendEvent:event];and [self resetIdleTimer]; implementation.Its helpful to me.

Comment: Its going Cool. Thank you.